# Progressbar in ListView issue when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, progress-bar

I am implementing a listview to display members separated by their team. There are progressbars which display each member job weight and how much they finished so far. The list seems to display right but when I scroll up and down, the progress bars changed unexpectedly. Here's the code.

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

private static final int STATE_UNKNOWN = 0;

private int requiredJob;
private static final int STATE_SECTIONED_CELL = 1;
private static final int STATE_REGULAR_CELL = 2;
private int[] mCellStates;

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int requiredJob) {
    super(context, cursor);
    mCellStates = cursor == null ? null : new int[cursor.getCount()];
    this.requiredJob=requiredJob;
}

@Override
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    super.changeCursor(cursor);
    mCellStates = cursor == null ? null : new int[cursor.getCount()];
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    int memJob, memDone;
    final  ViewHolder holder= (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

    boolean needSeparator = false;
    final int position = cursor.getPosition();

    String team= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_TEAM));

    switch (mCellStates[position]) {
        case STATE_SECTIONED_CELL:
            needSeparator = true;
            break;

        case STATE_REGULAR_CELL:
            needSeparator = false;
            break;

        case STATE_UNKNOWN:
        default:
            if (position == 0) {
                needSeparator = true;
            } else {

                cursor.moveToPosition(position-1);
                String str=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_TEAM));
                if(!str.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(team))) {
                    needSeparator=true;
                }

                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            }

            mCellStates[position] = needSeparator ? STATE_SECTIONED_CELL : STATE_REGULAR_CELL;
            break;
    }

    if (needSeparator) {
        holder.separator.setText(team);
        holder.separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else{
        holder.separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.member.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_MEMBER)));

    memJob=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_MEMBER_JOB));
    memDone=(int)cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_MEMBER_JOB_DONE));
    holder.pBar.getLayoutParams().width=(int)(400*memJob/requiredJob);
    holder.pBar.setMax(memJob);
    holder.pBar.setProgress(memDone);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder();
    holder.separator=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.sep_team);
    holder.member=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.member);
    holder.pBar=(MyProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.pBar);

    v.setTag(holder);
    return v;
}
}
```

Hope you guys can help me to fix the code. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution. This can be solved by getting the width parameter first, then set it to the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
memJob=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_MEMBER_JOB));
memDone=(int)cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_MEMBER_JOB_DONE));
holder.pBar.getLayoutParams().width=(int)(400*memJob/requiredJob);
holder.pBar.setMax(memJob);
holder.pBar.setProgress(memDone);
```

To:

```
memJob=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_MEMBER_JOB));
memDone=(int)cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_MEMBER_JOB_DONE));
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pBar);
progressBar.getLayoutParams().width=(int)(400*memJob/requiredJob);
progressBar.setMax(memJob);
progressBar.setProgress(memDone);
```

This will get the actual progress bar from directly inside the bindView and should hopefully solve your problem. You can delete `holder.pBar=(MyProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.pBar); from newView.`